# multiplicity of irreducible components of S3 modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let V denote the 2 dimensional irreducible standard module for $S_3$. I want to find multiplicity of each of  irreducible components of $V^{\otimes ^{10}}$ , by writing the character for $V^{\otimes ^{10}}$. I wrote down the characters, but how to find the multiplicity of each of  irreducible components of $V^{\otimes ^{10}}$ using them?

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the character table for $S_3$?  You have to write the character for $V^{\otimes 10}$ as a linear combination of the irreducible characters of $S_3$.  The coefficients in that linear combination will be positive integers and are the multiplicities that you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, got it. It will have 171 copy of trivial module, 171 copy of sign module, and 341 copy of standard module.